# Are there F# Monogame templates?

Tags: xamarin, f#, monogame

I want to experiment with Monogame in F# using Xamarin on OSX. I am able to create a working C# Monogame project and a working F# Cocoa app, but not a working F# Monogame project.

What is the boiler-plate setup for an F# Monogame project?

Are there Monogame F# templates available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a solution but a work-around: create two projects, one C# Monogame project and one F# console application. Both of these templates should be installed with Xamarin and Monogame.

1. Create a C# Monogame project
2. Create an F# console application
3. Edit the `fsproj` file so that it has `OutputType` `Library`
4. Link the F# project to the Monogame project
5. Add the Monogame package to the F# library using nuget
6. Write your `Game` class in F#!

Aside from the hassle of creating two projects, the main problem I've found is that every reference used in the F# library also needs to be referenced in the C# library or you will get runtime errors. I'm sure a custom build script could be written to fix this.